# what could be the possible reasons that cause android.view.ViewInflate$InflateException: Binary xml file?

Tags: android, exception, inflate

what could be the possible reasons that cause  "android.view.ViewInflate$InflateException: Binary xml file " ?   Here are all the errors. I dont know why, everytime i created some project about Fragments, it prompts these errors.

```
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testfra/com.example.testfra.FragTestActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Fragment
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #8: Error inflating class Fragment
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:691)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:739)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:251)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1835)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.example.testfra.FragTestActivity.onCreate(FragTestActivity.java:12)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  ... 11 more
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.view.Fragment
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:61)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:552)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:636)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:66)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:653)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:678)
09-21 22:57:09.166: E/AndroidRuntime(674):  ... 21 more
```

Comment: There are many reasons why you could see this error. It should be easy to fix, but I don't feel like guessing. Please post all of your LogCat errors and the relevant code.

Answer (score 0):

That is caused by an error in a layout file or in a fragment or component that's used in the layout file. As errors in the xml are detected at edit time, you'll most probably have an error (like a NullPointerException) in a fragment or a view that you created that's used in the layout.
But you can't expect people to answer your question properly, if all you give us is one line from your logcat. Post the whole stacktrace, then someone can maybe point out to you what's wrong in your code. If possible, post the relevant bits of code, like the classes in your project that are generating the stacktrace.

Comment: i have paste all the error messages above, could you please take a look?